# Visual Studio 2019 Javascript - how to reference application root relative path?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

Per the old Visual Studio 2015 docs, we could use "~" to reference the application root path:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/ide/javascript-intellisense?view=vs-2015&redirectedfrom=MSDN#ReferenceDirectives

So we could use a reference path like this:
`/// <reference path='~/my/common/helpers/file.js' />`

In any other JS file (lets say ~/some/other/path/file2.js), and it would always resolve regardless of where it was, relatively. Now in VS2019 (and I believe also in VS2017), this doesn't work, and warns:

> TS6053 ... not found.

These reference paths still work if you remove the "~" and fix the path to be relative, but then it's unique/relative to the individual file (which means every file might be different - we can't just copy-paste throughout). For this project, we're still using plain old JS, no modules or TS. Does anyone know a workaround to use an application root relative path in VS2019?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **VS2017** and **VS2019** does not support `~` application-root-relative path so far. And I am not sure whether it is an issue or the Team has forgotten it because I got the same behavior as you described.

[I have reported it to our DC Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Why--cannot-work-on-preference-path-js/1364759?space=8&sort=newest&q=why+%7E).And you can vote it and add any comments if I did not describe it in detail. More votes will help get more attention from **Microsoft**.

**Since** the process takes a long time, so far, as a suggestion, you have to use the full path of the js file like this on VS2019:

```
/// <reference path='C:\xxx\my\common\helpers\file.js' />
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Not quite the answer I was hoping for, but it was the answer I was expecting - helps to know I'm not alone.